# Nginx - Error 403 al acceder /

Tags: php, nginx

Estoy trabajando utilizando el servidor web de **Nginx**, pero está arrojando un error 403 al acceder /, exceptuando al acceder /index.php directamente u otro archivo existente. Archivos y directorios inexistentes lanzan un error 403 también.

**Error 403 = Prohibido/Forbidden**

Este es mi archivo de configuración:

```
# Configuration file for website.com
server {
 # Listen on port 80
 listen 80;
 # This configuration file is only valid if the IP/hostname used is
 server_name website.com www.website.com;

 # Root directory
 root /home/web/website.com;
 # Index file
 index index.php;

 # Enables PageSpeed
 pagespeed on;
 # Images
 pagespeed DisableFilters lazyload_images;
 # Combine JavaScript/CSS
 pagespeed EnableFilters combine_javascript;
 pagespeed EnableFilters combine_css;
 # Caching
 #pagespeed ForceCaching on;
 pagespeed EnableFilters extend_cache;

  # Enables PHP
 location ~ \.php$ {
  fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
  fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
  fastcgi_index index.php;
  include fastcgi_params;
  fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
 }

 # Handle errors & front controller
 location / {
  # Errors
  #error_page 400 /error/400;
  #error_page 401 /error/401;
  #error_page 403 /error/403;
  #error_page 404 /error/404;
  #error_page 500 /error/500;
  # Front controller
  try_files $uri $uri/ @missing;
  # Maintenance mode (comment to disable)
  allow 186.104.226.198;
  deny all;
 }

 # Front controller
 location @missing {
  rewrite ^ /index.php last;
 }

 # Protects the app directory
 location /app {
  # Deny all requests to /app
  deny all;
  # Return a 403 forbidden error
  return 403;
 }

}
```

Al mismo tiempo, agradecería revisar si el **front controller** esta OK, porque no lo parece. Quiero que todas solicitudes de URI /loquesea/etc sean enviadas a index.php. Con PHP, uso delimitadores para separar cada URI string por el `/`.

Gracias por sus respuestas.

PS: Comenté las páginas de error pensando en que iba a solucionar el problema, pero en verdad no funcionó. Intenté eliminando varias reglas también, plus, la regla de `deny all` es porque el sitio esta en mantenimiento, pero veo que mi IP ha cambiado porque es dinámica y aún pude acceder a /index.php.

Answer (score 0):

En Nginx las rewrite rules para algo tan "simple" yo utilizaría

```
location / {
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
}
```

Esto reenvía todo al fichero index.php adjuntando los demás parámetros a continuación.

Tienes toda la info detallada en https://www.nginx.com/blog/creating-nginx-rewrite-rules/